# How can I write code to search the data in a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I imported an Excel sheet into a `DataGridView` using the following code, now how can I write code to search the data in the `DataGridView`.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim myconnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dataset As System.Data.DataSet
    Dim mycommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim path As String = "F:\Project Files\Excel sheet\SalesReport1.xlsx"

    myconnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + path + "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
    mycommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Source Data$] ", myconnection)
    dataset = New System.Data.DataSet

    mycommand.Fill(dataset)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables(0)

    myconnection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far?

Comment: You don't explain what you mean by "search the data", although even if you did I expect the question would be too broad.

Comment: That code wont compile.  You have a Catch with no Try.  Please post the real code.  Also stop thinking of the data as "in the `DataGridView`"; it is actually in a `DataTable` and it will be much faster to work with that than a UI control (if you dont throw it away).  A DGV is just how we show data to users.

Comment: ok i mean sort datagridview according to my need - thanx